# flutter http send empty body

Tags: http, flutter, dart

this is what i tried:

```
Future<User> guestLogin(String deviceID) async {
  var body = {
    "deviceid": deviceID,
  };

  var bodyEncoded = json.encode(body);

  Response response = await client.post(
    "$_baseURL/api/user/guest",
    body: bodyEncoded,
    headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
  );
  return User.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
}
```

but when i check it from serverside which coded by golang then i see that the body is empty. when i try it on postman its working well. Where is the problem?

Comment: What's the response status?

Comment: @ClaudioRedi it's 200

Comment: What do you expect as body?

Comment: a user model. @ClaudioRedi . But flutter send post body as empty

Comment: Hard to tell from the code you show. Do you own the api to check why the response is empty?

Comment: @ClaudioRedi the response is empty because flutter is sending post body as empty as i send it from flutter code. so there is no problem on serverside cause when i call it from postman its working well. And i logged into golang then i see that body is empty.

Comment: Posted `body` can't be null according the code you show. Maybe `deviceid` is null or empty?

Comment: @ClaudioRedi no i have debugged it and its not empty.

Comment: Have you tried specifying the encoding inside the post? Like: `encoding: utf8`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `jsonEncode(body)` instead of `json.encode(body)`

Comment: `jsonEncode(body)` and `json.encode(body)` are exactly the same @Ali Gürelli.... look at the definition https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.0/dart-convert/jsonEncode.html